# Is there a difference between 突然に and 突然のことで?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, adverbs

Are 突然に and 突然のことで just different ways to say the same thing?

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "突然のところで". Could you give me a whole sentence including it ?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I messed up. It is こと.

Answer (score 5):

- 突然に (*suddenly*) is mostly an adverb in the literal sense of the word, which is to say it usually modifies verbs and describes a certain aspect (namely, suddenness) of the way the actions denoted them take place.

> チャンスは突然(に)やってくる。(Opportunities come *suddenly*.)
>
> 電車は突然(に)停止した。(The train stopped *suddenly*.)

As indicated by (), the に can be (and often is) omitted.

- 突然のことで is an adverbial phrase that modifies clauses and serves to give the reason/cause (that is, the reason/cause of suddenness) for the particular events or situations expressed by them.

> 突然のことで、なんと申し上げてよいか言葉もありません。(*It being so sudden*, I have no words at the ready to offer.)
>
> 突然のことで申し訳ありません。(I am sorry *for it being so sudden*.)
>
> 突然のことで、驚きました。(I was startled *by the suddenness of it*.)